# How to update AWS CLI tools on AWS Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am running "Amazon Linux AMI release 2010.11.2". I noticed that the AWS CLI tools are outdated.

I have tried to use yum update and yum upgrade but it's telling me that the packages are already at their latest version.

How would I update the CLI tools, and how would I update the distribution itself? E.g. to a newer version of AWS Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Amazon Linux AMI 2011.02 Beta Release Notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/latest-release-notes/)

The correct procedure for updating AWS Linux AMI is:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/distro-upgrade.sh
```

This also installs the latest versions of CLI Tools.

Answer (score 20):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI -- Ok so It's a dead thread but if someone land here, there is a new release of a AWS CLI (http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) which includes api for ALL web services

Comment: This is not a forum; there is no such thing as a "dead thread" here.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way via YUM `sudo yum update aws-cli`